# Solving a basic limit - do not know the solution

Tags: limits

So the limit is:

$\lim_{x \rightarrow 2} \frac{2x-4}{x^2+2x-6}$

So is it zero from the beginning. Because 0/something is zero, but that is stinky. And I am practicing from the book I do not have solution.
Symbolab an Wolframalpha are also saying it is zero.

But if it is taken with L'Hospital's rule it is 1/3. I do not get what am I doing wrong. I want to solve it adjusting the polynomials.

Thanks.

Comment: the denominator is not zero,so you can't apply L'hospital rule

Comment: You can only apply l’Hospital’s rule in certain situations; this is not one of them. $0$ is correct.

Comment: "0/something is zero": provided that something is not also zero.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use  L'Hospital's rule as there does not exist $\frac{0}{0}$ or other specific condition for  L'Hospital's rule. Hence $0$ is the correct value for the limit.

Answer (score 0):

Since the denominator is non-zero, then you can't use L'Hopital's rule.
As a first plan, when you have a rational function like this, plug x=2 in the numerator and denominator, if the denominator isn't 0, then you are good to go. If not, you may have to use L'Hopital (provided you can), or any other tool at your disposal.

Answer (score 0):

If $f(a)=0$ while $g(a)\ne0$ then

$$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0$$ because in the vicinity of $a$, the ratio get smaller and smaller.

If $f(a)=0$ while $g(a)=0$, you cannot say (because the ratio could take any value). Anyway in this case L'Hospital pertains
$$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}.$$

Compare

[image]

and

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> What are Limits?
>
> Limits are the way to find the value of a function when we get an
>   indeterminate form of a number (like $\frac 0 0$ which cannot be
>   represented in Real number Line Axis).
>
> When we plot such functions where there is an indeterminate form at a
>   certain value of $x$, then we don't get holes or gaps (try yourself!).
>   Why? because they are not defined at a point but everywhere near them,
>   so, that point is indefinitely small.
>
> Limits are the mathematical way to say almost when it's too small, so,

unless you get a number in the indeterminate form, limits are not useful in such cases. So, next time, just simply put the value and evaluate the function like just any other function ;)

Here in your case when we plug the value of $x$, we simply get 0, that's what the limit of the function is!

**Note: It's also possible that Limit of a function is not defined at a point, but the direct value exists! think yourself for such examples :P :)**